# JavaFx unwanted white Corner - TextArea

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I want to change my TextArea's colour to black and I've changed the design a bit by using CSS. But there are some unwanted white spots left and I don't know how to remove them.

[image]

```
.black-card{
-fx-text-fill: #d4d4d4;
-fx-control-inner-background: #1b191a;
-fx-text-box-border: transparent;
-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-prompt-text-fill: #a2a2a2;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
```

This is my css code for the TextArea and im setting the Style with     `mytextarea.getStyleClass().add("black-card");`

Changing the root-background colour doesn't change anything about this, so my conclusion is that I've done something wrong in the CSS code but can't seem to find my Error.

Thanks in advance, Jasper.

Comment: I think you need to set the content as well for example: `.text-area .content{ -fx-background-color: black;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply the background radius to the text area's content:

```css
.black-card{

    -fx-text-fill: #d4d4d4;
    -fx-control-inner-background: #1b191a;
    -fx-text-box-border: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: #a2a2a2;

}
.black-card .content {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it :)

Comment: sorry, I had to wait a few minutes in order to do so. And sorry for asking a duplicate then, I couldn't find one that helped me.

Comment: @mejasper No worries: I couldn't find the others either - I just remember them...